# Django foreign key with different model field values

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create a foreign key relationship in a model, where it actually provides a select dropdown for the model form based on another field value of the model. Normally dropdown shows the values of `__str__` methods return value. I want to keep this also since it used in other places.

For example, consider two models `Order` and `Item`.

`Item` have fields called `item_code` and `item_name`.
`__str__` will return `item_name`.

`Order` model will have foreign key to `Item` model. But I want it provides the `item_code` field values in the dropdown for item selection.

How can I achieve this without changing general foreign key behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You would do this in the form, by defining a subclass of ModelChoiceField with a custom `label_from_instance` method, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

Comment: @Adem No, that's for customising the field that the *value* comes from, not the representation. For reasons I've never understood, there is no easy way to specify that the representation comes from a specific field - you need to customise the field as I mention, which is explained in the paragraph after the one you link to.